# Having trouble with mysql relationships?

Tags: mysql, many-to-many, relationship, one-to-many

I need two tables, one that shows a one to many relationship using three tables, and another table that shows a many to many relationship.  I have managed to do the first 2 with were a query involving just one table, and a one to many involving 2 tables.

One Table Query:

```
SELECT LastName, FirstName, City 
FROM Customer
WHERE City = 'Lutherville-Timonium'
```

One to many involving 2 tables:

```
SELECT b.BrandName, m.ModelName
FROM Brand b, Model m
WHERE b.BrandID = m.BrandID
```

Here is my code:

```
    DROP DATABASE IF EXISTS FinalProject;

CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS FinalProject;

Use FinalProject;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Brand
(
 BrandID INT,
 BrandName VARCHAR(45),
 PRIMARY KEY(BrandID)
);

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Model
(
 ModelName VARCHAR(45),
 BrandID INT,
 PRIMARY KEY(ModelName),
 FOREIGN KEY(BrandID) REFERENCES Brand(BrandID)
);

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Platform
(
 PlatformID INT,
 Platform VARCHAR(45),
 PRIMARY KEY(PlatformID)
);

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Computer
(
 ComputerID INT,
 ModelName VARCHAR(45),
 PlatformID INT,
 Processor VARCHAR(45),
 Memory VARCHAR(45),
 HardDrive VARCHAR(45),
 OperatingSystem VARCHAR(45),
 PRIMARY KEY(ComputerID),
 FOREIGN KEY(ModelName) REFERENCES Model(ModelName),
 FOREIGN KEY(PlatformID) REFERENCES Platform(PlatformID)
);

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Customer
(
 CustomerID INT,
 LastName VARCHAR(45),
 FirstName VARCHAR(45),
 Address VARCHAR(45),
 Zip INT,
 City VARCHAR(45),
 State VARCHAR(2),
 PhoneNumber INT,
 Email VARCHAR(45),
 PRIMARY KEY(CustomerID)
);

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Employee
(
 EmployeeID INT,
 Position VARCHAR(45),
 LastName VARCHAR(45),
 FirstName VARCHAR(45),
 Address VARCHAR(45),
 Zip INT,
 City VARCHAR(45),
 State VARCHAR(2),
 PhoneNumber INT,
 Email VARCHAR(45),
 PRIMARY KEY(EmployeeID)
);

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Invoice
(
 InvoiceID INT,
 CustomerID INT,
 Total DECIMAL(19,4),
 EmployeeID INT,
 PRIMARY KEY(InvoiceID),
 FOREIGN KEY(CustomerID) REFERENCES Customer(CustomerID),
 FOREIGN KEY(EmployeeID) REFERENCES Employee(EmployeeID)
);

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS InvoiceItem
(
 InvoiceItemID INT,
 InvoiceID INT,
 ComputerID INT,
 PRIMARY KEY(InvoiceItemID),
 FOREIGN KEY(InvoiceID) REFERENCES Invoice(InvoiceID),
 FOREIGN KEY(ComputerID) REFERENCES Computer(ComputerID)
);

INSERT INTO Brand
 (BrandID, BrandName)
VALUES
 (101, 'Toshiba'),
 (102, 'ASUS'),
 (103, 'Dell'),
 (104, 'Samsung'),
 (105, 'MSI'),
 (106, 'Apple');

INSERT INTO Model
 (ModelName, BrandID)
VALUES 
 ('Satellite L50D-BBT2N22', 101),
 ('Transformer Book T100TAF', 102),
 ('Inspiron 3000', 103),
 ('ATIV One 7 Curved', 104),
 ('GE60 2PE APACHE PRO', 105),
 ('Summer 2014 13 in. MacBook Pro', 106),
 ('Wind Box DC111', 105),
 ('Alienware 17', 103),
 ('ATIV Book 9 Plus', 104);

INSERT INTO Platform
 (PlatformID, Platform)
VALUES
 (001, 'Laptop'),
 (002, 'Desktop');

INSERT INTO Computer
 ( ComputerID, ModelName, Processor, Memory, HardDrive, OperatingSystem, PlatformID)
VALUES
 (178045, 'Satellite L50D-BBT2N22', 'AMD Quad-Core A4-6210', '4GB', '1TB', 'Windows 8.1', 001),
 (178046, 'Transformer Book T100TAF', 'Intel Bay Trail-T Quad Core Z3735 1.33 GHz', '2GB', '32GB', 'Windows 8.1', 001),
 (178047, 'Inspiron 3000', 'Intel Core i5-4460', '8GB', '1TB', 'Windows 8.1', 002),
 (178048, 'ATIV One 7 Curved', 'Intel Core i5 Processor 5200U', '8GB', '1TB', 'Windows 8.1', 002),
 (178049, 'GE60 2PE APACHE PRO', 'Intel Core i7 Processor', '16GB', '1TB', 'Windows 8.1', 001),
 (178050, 'Summer 2014 13 in. MacBook Pro', '2.5GHz dual-core Intel Core i5', '4GB', '500GB', 'OS X Yosemite', 001),
 (178051, 'Wind Box DC111', 'Intel Celeron Dual Core', '4GB', ' 500GB', 'Windows 8.1', 002),
 (178052, 'Alienware 17', 'Intel Core i7', '8GB', '1TB', 'WIndows 8.1', 001),
 (178053, 'ATIV Book 9 Plus', 'Intel Core i5', '8GB', '128GB', 'Windows 8.1', 001);

INSERT INTO Customer
 (CustomerID, LastName, FirstName, Address, Zip, City, State, PhoneNumber, Email)
VALUES
 (14670, 'Franks', 'Robert', '2905 North Ave.', 21218, 'Baltimore', 'MD', 443-875-9090, 'r.franks@gmail.com'),
 (14671, 'Smith', 'Anthony', '28 Rhodes Pl.', 21093, 'Lutherville-Timonium', 'MD', 410-252-6542, 'asmith@me.com'),
 (14672, 'Anderson', 'Mary', '1784 Cranbrook Dr.', 21093, 'Lutherville-Timonium', 'MD', 410-687-8235, 'm.anderson@comcast.net'),
 (14673, 'Keith', 'Toby', '987 Rodeo Dr.', 21093, 'Lutherville-Timonium', 'MD', 443-267-0900, 'not_that_toby.keith@gmail.com'),
 (14674, 'Karwacki', 'Ryan', '16200 Yeoho Rd', 21152, 'Hereford', 'MD', 410-350-4456, 'r.karwacki44@gmail.com'),
 (14675, 'Yancey', 'Marcus', '165 Twilight Ct.', 21218, 'Baltimore', 'MD', 443-908-9087, 'm.yancey35@aol.com');

INSERT INTO Employee
 (EmployeeID, Position, LastName, FirstName, Address, Zip, City, State, PhoneNumber, Email)
VALUES
 (100001, 'CEO', 'Brocato', 'Christopher', '26 Rhodes Pl.', 21093, 'Lutherville-Timonium', 'MD', 410-812-0548, 'c.brocat0@prestigeww.com'),
 (100893, 'Location Manager', 'White', 'Walter', '687 Winning Dr.', 21117, 'Owings Mills', 'MD', 410-674-8890, 'w.white@prestigeww.com'),
 (100894, 'Computer Engineer', 'Pinkman', 'Jesse', '15 Pot Spring Cr.', 21093, 'Lutherville-Timonium', 'MD', 443-897-5467, 'j.pinkman@prestigeww.com'),
 (100895, 'Computer Engineer', 'Fring', 'Gustavo', '8796 Westmister Br.', 21117, 'Owings Mills', 'MD', 443-098-1111, 'g.fring@prestigeww.com'),
 (100896, 'Software Specialist', 'Boetticher', 'Gale', '7845 Sunny Ln.', 21093, 'Lutherville-Timonium', 'MD', 443-896-5674, 'g.boetticher@prestigeww.com'),
 (100087, 'Lawyer', 'Goodman', 'Saul', '7823 Goodman Ln.', 21093, 'Lutherville-Timonium', 'MD', 410-657-8900, 's.goodman@prestigeww.com');

INSERT INTO Invoice
 (InvoiceID, Total, CustomerID, EmployeeID)
VALUES
 (237871, 115.99, 14670, 100893),
 (237872, 87.89, 14671, 100894),
 (237873, 476.95, 14672, 100895),
 (237874, 314.95, 14673, 100896),
 (237875, 45.96, 14674, 100001),
 (237876, 79.84, 14675, 100087);

INSERT INTO InvoiceItem
 (InvoiceItemID, InvoiceID, ComputerID)
VALUES
 (1008, 237871, 178045),
 (1009, 237872, 178046),
 (1010, 237873, 178047),
 (1011, 237874, 178048),
 (1012, 237875, 178049),
 (1013, 237876, 178050);
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated
Thanks.

Comment: Which tables are you trying to join together?

Comment: I was trying to join Brand, Model, and Computer but couldn't figure it out

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should do the job:

```
SELECT *
FROM computer c

LEFT OUTER JOIN model m ON m.ModelName = c.ModelName
LEFT OUTER JOIN brand b ON b.BrandID = m.BrandID
```

You may want to change the returned fields as per your requirements. Good luck with the project.

=== Update - To order it how you have requested:

```
SELECT *
FROM brand b

LEFT OUTER JOIN model m ON m.BrandID = b.BrandID
LEFT OUTER JOIN computer c ON c.ModelName = m.ModelName
```

=== Update no.2 - To include new 'platform' table

```
SELECT *
FROM brand b

LEFT OUTER JOIN model m ON m.BrandID = b.BrandID
LEFT OUTER JOIN computer c ON c.ModelName = m.ModelName
LEFT OUTER JOIN platform p ON p.platformID = c.PlatformID
```

=== Update no.3 - The above covers 1-many relationships for 2,3 and 4 tables. To add a many to many relationship you would probably want to look at the computer to invoice relationship as a computer can be in more than one invoice AND an invoice can (in real life) contain more than one computer. The initially proposed data structure doesn't allow for this. Adding a table for *InvoiceItem* would achieve this.

relationship between computer and invoice would be many to many [Computer (many) - (many) Invoice] This is achieved by adding a link table between them :

```
Computer (1)-(Many) InvoiceItem (many)-(1) Invoice
```

=== Update no.4
To achieve this, remove computerID from the invoice table and add the new table InvoiceItem with the following fields - InvoiceItemID, InvoiceNumber, ComputerID. The query to then retrieve the invoice items from the database would be:

```
SELECT *
FROM Invoice i
LEFT OUTER JOIN InvoiceItem ii ON ii.InvoiceNumber = i.InvoiceNumber
LEFT OUTER JOIN Computer c ON c.computerID = ii.computerID
```

You could extend this to also include the other computer related tables with:

```
SELECT *
FROM Invoice i
LEFT OUTER JOIN InvoiceItem ii ON ii.InvoiceNumber = i.InvoiceNumber
LEFT OUTER JOIN Computer c ON c.computerID = ii.computerID
LEFT OUTER JOIN Model m ON m.ModelName = c.ModelName
LEFT OUTER JOIN Brand b ON b.BrandID = m.BrandID
LEFT OUTER JOIN platform p ON p.platformID = c.PlatformID
```

If I was being really picky, I would ditch linking on names, and just use IDs if a model name changes slightly the queries would no longer work. Using purely IDs prevents this.

Comment: OK, thankyou very much, and just to make sure, this is the one to many relationship...

Comment: 1 brand -> Many Models -> Many Computers.. it could be re-written if you prefer to SELECT * FROM brand b LEFT OUTER JOIN model m ON m.BrandID = b.brandID LEFT OUTER JOIN computer c ON c.ModelName = m.ModelName

Comment: If you add another computer that uses the same model, the model will show twice, once for each computer that uses it. Add another Model to a brand and add a computer for that and the brand will show multiple times. Your current data doesn't have anything to illustrate the one->many relationship

Comment: Ok, what i am getting from you is that as of now I only have a one to one relationship.  So if I were to add more than one model per brand that would make it a one to many relationship.

Comment: The database relationship *IS* one to many but your data doesn't illustrate this, so yes :) Adding another model per brand or computer per model would highlight this. Any other questions, just ask :)

Comment: OK I removed Platform from the table that it was in and created a new table named Platform.  I also added a few more computers so that i would have multiple computers and platforms for a few of the brands.  I put the changed code into the original question at the top of the page.

Comment: Ok, I can alter the query to include the platform elements easily. What is the target outcome here? Also do you want to learn how to do it or just have the answer? I'll update my answer to include the new platform table also shortly.

Comment: I want a one to many relationship showing one brand and multiple models, and another one to many relationship showing one brand with multiple models and platforms.  And whatever is easier for you, I also really appreciate it.

Comment: Ok, going back to your initial question; you have the one to many relationship with 2,3 and 4 tables. The thing you are missing is the many-to-many relationship. To do this you would need a table where the items can be in another multiple times be also be included in that table many times.. For you the most obvious place is invoice as a computer model can be in many invoices, but an invoice can also have many computers. To enable this properly though you will need another table that includes the items in an invoice, e.g. InvoiceItem as you currently only allow 1 computer per invoice.

Comment: This would give you: Brand (1)-(many) Model (1)-(many) Computer (many)-(many) Invoice.. But would actually be represented by this Brand (1)-(many) Model (1)-(many) Computer (1)-(many) *InvoiceItem* (many)-(1) Invoice. Does that make sense? I'll update my answer to include this as it's difficult to read in comments.

Comment: Ok, I see what your saying, but what keys would go into the table

Comment: You would remove computerID from the invoice table and the new table would be InvoiceItemID, InvoiceID, ComputerID. I'll update answer to include the data.

Comment: Ok, I have updated the answer to include the requirements for the many-many relationship.

Comment: I noticed that you used invoiceNumber rather than ID so I changed my answer to reflect that. So long as invoice numbers *cant* change you would be ok. As per my comment at the bottom of the answer, I generally use ID's for everything so would have InvoiceNumber *and* InvoiceNumber but that's probably overkill for your project.

Comment: So they are different

Comment: Different in what way? - Number is perfectly fine. The only time it could *ever* be an issue is if you had to change the number of an invoice - for accounting reasons, maybe.

Comment: If it were me, I would add ID, though. :)

Comment: forget about that last question

Comment: Did it all make sense? Anything else I can help you with?

Comment: If that is correct than I believe I can finish it from here

Comment: Small error, your foreign key, for Invoice, still references CustomerID :)

Comment: Do you understand what I have done by creating the link table between Computer and Invoice? If you are unsure, just say. There are parts that I'm skipping as I'm assuming you know those parts. Just as you have correctly noticed that customerID doesn't need to be in both invoice *and* computer. To decide where things should be just think which scenario can happen to link a customer to either a computer or an invoice. which happens first may be help you to decide. This holds true for much of DB design :)

Comment: If all is good with that could you accept the answer as correct :), thanks

Comment: SO I want to remove CustomerID from invoice aswell?

Comment: This depends.. in your imaginary company. does an invoice get raised for a computer before the computer is available, or is the computer built and then the customer chooses one? It is valid to include it one both. Purists will sometimes say this is wrong as is is potentially redundant data but there are many cases where it's correct eg. The customer asks for a specific computer to be built, you need the customer reference against the pc, but the invoice doesn't exist at this point. But if the invoice is raised when a customer orders a machine the customerID should be linked there, not in pc

Comment: This is all to do with [data normalisation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization).. You will aim for 3rd normal form for most basic applications but 4th and 5th normal form are required for some projects.

Comment: Ok I see what your saying.  I really appreciate you taking the time to help.  And I do understand how to use MYSQL, I am just struggling with how to code relationships.  My teacher is very hard to learn from and was not very helpful when I went to him for help.

Comment: Apolgies, I've noticed that it's not on computer. I thought it was in an earlier version of the DB.. Keep it on invoice :)

Comment: No problem.. I think it's important to understand the relationships and why they are like that before you actually try to program them in SQL.. Read the linked article on data normalisation.

Comment: I don't know if you can still see this, but thank you so much, got a 100% on the assignment